# Typing multiline expressions in nix repl

Tags: read-eval-print-loop, nix

[This PR](https://github.com/edolstra/nix-repl/pull/21) seems to indicate that it was at least a feature in `nix repl`'s predecessor, `nix-repl`.

When I try to replicate the example in the PR, I get errors.

```
nix-repl> rec {
error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, at (string):1:6

nix-repl>             a = b.foo;
error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting end of file, at (string):1:7

nix-repl>             b.foo.bar = 12;
error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting end of file, at (string):1:23

nix-repl>           }
error: syntax error, unexpected '}', at (string):1:11

nix-repl>
```

Comment: I think you're right. I like to iterate on a file with `:a` and `:r` instead.

Comment: The linked `nix repl` PR was [reverted](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/commit/f3c85f9eb395b13790d1fced05665125e2ec81ca) because it wasn't used in `nix repl`. Maybe it can still be part of a complete solution.